# Format an array of data, join to a single string, and add the character between every 2 indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

let's say I have an array of data like so:

```
var data = [ '10' '15', '10', '34', '40', '0', '10', '15' ];
```

in the end I want the data to me format to be joined and into one string, like so:

```
var data = 'm10 15 l10 34 l40 0 l10 15';
```

**Rules:**

a. 'm' will always be the first letter

b. 'l' will always be the following letters.

---

**approch**

I think using Modulus (%2) may work?  but how would I loop through this properly, add the proper letters, and join into 1 long string?

Comment: `data.map(function (val, idx) { return (idx % 2 === 0 ? "l" : "") + val; }).join(" ");` almost gets you there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following, a simple loop using the modulus operator, could work:

```
// start with an empty string
var full_str = '';

// iterate over each data element
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
        // add the leading 'm'
        full_str = 'm';
    } else {
        // if not the first element, add a space
        full_str += ' ';

        // if this is %2, add an `l`
        if ((i > 0) && ((i % 2) === 0)) {
            full_str += 'l';
        }
    }

    // add the current number to the string
    full_str += data[i];
}
```

As pointed out in comments, if the `data` array is really large then performing the "first element check" within the loop itself will be far less efficient than doing it outside. In that case, if the array is really large or if you're future-planning, the following would be similar but more efficient than the above:

```
// start with an empty string
var full_str = '';

if (data.length > 0) {
    // add the first number with a prefixed `m`
    full_str = 'm' + data[0];

    // iterate over each element, starting with the second
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        // add a space before this element
        full_str += ' ';

        // if this is %2, add an `l`
        if ((i % 2) === 0) {
            full_str += 'l';
        }

        // add the current number to the string
        full_str += data[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: While yours will work, I don't like putting conditional logic for "is this the first element" in a loop, I like to put that outside the loop for better readability and optimization.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight That's a matter of preference, and the actual "need" depends on the size of the array. I actually think my way is more readable than yours (again, personal preference), but I do agree that for larger arrays yours is more efficient (for an empty array, yours will throw an error though).

Comment: This is a lot of code, given that the one-liner given by Ian in the comments is almost enough (just one `substring` and one string concatenation away from a full solution.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet Define "lot of work"? Perhaps you mean "a lot of lines" instead since technically they do the exact same thing. Both iterate over the entire list and create a string - his uses built in array functions and mine writes out the full loop that shows the actual concepts "behind the scenes". If the OP was unable to do *this*, the one-liner won't really help them learn much... regardless, I'm all for shorter and more concise code so feel free to recommend the OP in whichever direction you prefer =]

Comment: @newfurniturey: I almost immediately edited my comment to say "a lot of code", which is what I really meant.  I just wanted to note that the concise code was perfectly readable; there is almost no loss switching to that version, and plenty to gain by using the appropriate abstraction (that is, `map`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var out = '';

out = 'm' + data[0] + ' ';
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) out += 'l';
  out += data[i] + ' ';
}

console.log(out);
```

should work.